# The closure of a set in the point-wise topology

Tags: general-topology

I am reading through the section on Function Spaces in Stephan Willard's General Topology and I am having trouble understanding a particular statement.

Let $Y^X$ denote the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$.

What is meant by the following:

> Let $\mathcal{F}\subseteq Y^X$. For each $x\in X$, the set
>   $\{f(x):f\in \mathcal{F}\}$ has compact closure in $Y^X$.

My problem is that the set may not even be a subset of $Y^X$, so how does it make sense to talk about the closure in $Y^X$?

Am I misinterpreting something here? Should it not say $Y$ instead of $Y^X$? Is this a misprint?

Comment: You're probably right - should be in $Y$.

Comment: Yeah, otherwise it makes no sense!

Comment: $f\in \mathcal F$ we have $f:X\to Y$ so for any $x\in X$ we have $f(x)\in Y $ hence $\{f(x);f\in \mathcal F \}\subset Y. $ I hope you find your way now. So your stament meant that the set $\{f(x);f\in \mathcal F \}$ is realtively compact in $Y$.